# Boostrap menu items show separately in vertical list

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap code which is not showing the desired result. The menu items shows separately at the upper right corner of web page whereas they should be in the horizontal strip (like a tab structure). What is wrong with code?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
  <div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">CMS System </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>


  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: like a tab structure

Comment: yes like a tab structure. horizontal items on strip

Comment: so to the page right side you need the tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some extra bit of style. May be there is an issue with the version of the bootstrap css you have used as well.

```css
.navbar .container-fluid>.navbar-header {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.nav>li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">CMS System </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I copied your code, it worked without including the custom css you provided.

Comment: @SumairaSamar, that's really grate to know:)

Answer (score 1):

You could change

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
```

to

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-expand">
```

making the navbar horizontal

Answer (score 0):

using latest version of bootstrap no need of css, you can check the below solution.

I hope this will solve the issue.

**Note**: Added some css extra classes for styling the background of navigations

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-end">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav text-right">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```